# How to avoid images being uploaded to google's proxy server in Emailers

Tags: email, dynamic, html-email, image-uploading, email-attachments

I am creating an e-mailer, Where images are getting rendered from my server.

```
<img src="http://myserver.com/createimg.php"/>
```

As shown in the example above will outputs an image with proper header. But When I try to send the e-mailer from mailchimp or PHPMailer, Images are getting created and uploaded to google's proxy server. I need the images need to be created when a person access from his email client. How can I overcome this issue.

Comment: Sounds like an arms race in the making. What if somebody posts tomorrow "I'm building a spam filter, and I'm trying to check if the image from `http://example.com/createimg.php` is actually spam?". In the end, data is just data, and cannot observe its environment. The pixels of your image cannot determine if there are human eyeballs looking at them.

Answer (score 1):

This is a security matter. Google does this to prevent loading a webpage, which the user has no idea about, and can potentially run malicious scripts.

There's only a whitelist mechanism for users of Google Accounts, [here](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3299041?hl=en), which may not apply to your case here.